# Upload image code is not working fully

Tags: php, image, image-uploading

I have the following code that works correctly providing the number of images I upload is less than 3. If I try and upload 3 or images then it uploads one less than I selected. I.e If I select 3 images to upload only 2 upload, 4 then 3 upload etc. However the insert saves the filenames of the images to a database - if I have 4 images all 4 filenames are saved

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = $currentdir."/uploaded_images/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;


echo $name.'<br>';

 if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
     foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) { 
 //echo $name.'<br>';

    $insert_offline_order_item_totals = "INSERT INTO offline_order_images
        VALUE ('','$invoice_number_2','','','','$name');";
        //echo $insert_offline_order_item_totals.'<br><br>';
            mysql_query($insert_offline_order_item_totals, $connection);



    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }          
    if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
        if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
            $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file

            echo $count;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I Could do with some advice as to why this is happening.

Comment: It's `VALUES` and not `VALUE`. Just say that's a typo.

Comment: *"However the insert that inserts the correct amount of filenames."* - This isn't a proper sentence; it seems unfinished. What do you mean by that exactly? Plus, did you not read my first comment?

Comment: I have always used VALUE and had no issue with it - sorry to be clear the insert saves the filenames of the images to a database - if I have 4 images all 4 filenames are saved

Comment: [**Not by what MySQL states**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) unless you have a custom function called `VALUE()`

Comment: As stated I have always used VALUE and never had any problems - my colleagues are the same they vary but if they use value they have never had a problem

Comment: Well I'm going to try this right now then.

Comment: Well I'll be a Monkey's Uncle, it does work! lol! I didn't know that. I learned something today lol! However, that's for MySQL. I'm not sure if Oracle and others besides MySQL accept it (VALUE). I'll have to research that.

Comment: Yeah we only deal with MySQL so its fine for us - still struggling on my original question - it doesn't seem to go into the if the correct amount of times

Comment: .JPG is not valid, use strtolower for pathinfo

Comment: That doesn't quite add up though as jpg files do upload when I have tested it its just that the correct amount of images don't upload if there are more than 3

Comment: I would suggest add an if statement for name $path.$name as well.